# System.env and values in Properties file are not being read on worker Nodes of Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I do have a multi node spark cluster and submitting my spark program on node where master resides.

When the job submitted to worker nodes, the HOSTNAME paramter  is giving null value. Here is the line where properties are being read as null.

System.getenv(HOSTNAME) is not being read from worker node.

```
        System.out.println("line 76 System.getenv(HOSTNAME)=" + System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
```

AUDIT_USER, AUDIT_PASSWORD also null when being read(they both were on properties file).

If i submit job with one node i have no issues with these parameters. But, if u submit job on standalone mode with 6 nodes i am getting this issue.

I have created the same folder for properties file on all nodes.

Here is my code. could you please let me know why System.env is not giving null and my properties are null?

```
package com.fb.cpd.myapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.common.TopicAndPartition;
import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata;
import kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;

public class GenericLogic implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenericLogic.class);
    private PropertiesConfiguration props;
    private Producer<String, String> producer = null;
    private Future<RecordMetadata> receipt = null;
    private RecordMetadata receiptInfo = null;
    private ConnectToRDBMS auditor = null;
    private ConnectToRDBMS df = null;

    private static String myId = null;

    private Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> getOffsets(String topic) throws SQLException {
        String appName = "myapp";
        String TopicName = topic;
        Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> topicMap = new HashMap<>(); //
        System.out.println("line 64 before making connection");

        try {
            props = new PropertiesConfiguration("/app/lock/conf/empty.properties");
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Line 70");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("line 76 System.getenv(HOSTNAME)=" + System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
            auditor = new ConnectToRDBMS(System.getenv("HOSTNAME"), "lockSparkCollector", null, null, null, null, null,
                    0, props.getString("AUDIT_USER"), props.getString("AUDIT_PASSWORD"),
                    props.getString("AUDIT_DB_URL"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("ASSERT: run() ERROR CONNECTING TO AUDIT DB " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("line 64 after making connection");

        Statement stmt = null;

        String query = "select va_application, topic_name, partition_id, from_offset,until_offset from lock_spark_offsets where va_application = "
                + "'" + appName + "'" + " and topic_name= " + "'" + TopicName + "'";
        System.out.println("query" + query);
        System.out.println("before query exection");
        try {
            stmt = auditor.dbConnection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("line 81");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("line 83");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("pass 1 of Resultset");
                System.out.println("getOffsets=" + topic.trim() + " " + rs.getInt("partition_id") + " "
                        + rs.getString("until_offset") + " " + rs.getString("until_offset"));
                Integer partition = rs.getInt("partition_id");

                TopicAndPartition tp = new TopicAndPartition(topic.trim(), partition);
                System.out.println("102");
                Long.parseLong(rs.getString("until_offset"));
                topicMap.put(tp, Long.parseLong(rs.getString("until_offset")));
                System.out.println("105");

            }
            System.out.println("after populating topic map");

        } catch (

        SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("printing exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                System.out.println("closing statement");
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
        return topicMap;
    }

    public void setDefaultProperties() {
        FileChangedReloadingStrategy strategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
        strategy.setRefreshDelay(10000);
        System.out.println("Line 45");
        // supply the properties file.
        try {
            props = new PropertiesConfiguration("/app/lock/conf/empty.properties");
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Line 51");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        props.setReloadingStrategy(strategy);
        System.out.println("Line 56");

        // Producer configs
        if (!props.containsKey("acks")) {
            props.setProperty("acks", "1");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("retries")) {
            props.setProperty("retries", "1000");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("compression.type")) {
            props.setProperty("compression.type", "gzip");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("request.timeout.ms")) {
            props.setProperty("request.timeout.ms", "600000");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("batch.size")) {
            props.setProperty("batch.size", "32768");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("buffer.memory")) {
            props.setProperty("buffer.memory", "134217728");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("block.on.buffer.full")) {
            props.setProperty("block.on.buffer.full", "true");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("SHUTDOWN")) {
            props.setProperty("SHUTDOWN", "false");
        }

        if (!props.containsKey("producer.topic")) {
            props.setProperty("producer.topic", "mytopic1");
        }

        Properties producer_props = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(props);

        producer_props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", props.getString("target.bootstrap.servers"));
        producer_props.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        producer_props.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"); // ????

        this.producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producer_props);
        System.out.println("Line 107");

    }

    public void PublishMessages(String st) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Line 111");
            String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
            System.out.println("Started Producing...");

            receipt = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(props.getString("producer.topic"), key, // Key
                    st));
            System.out.println("After Completion of Producing Producing");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in PublishMessages ");
        }

    }

    public void DBConnect() {
        try {
            auditor = new ConnectToRDBMS(System.getenv("HOSTNAME"), "myapp", props.getString("consumer.topic"), null,
                    null, null, null, 0, props.getString("AUDIT_USER"), props.getString("AUDIT_PASSWORD"),
                    props.getString("AUDIT_DB_URL"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("ASSERT: run() ERROR CONNECTING TO AUDIT DB " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }

    private void writeToDB(Long startTime, Integer partnId, String fromOffset, String untilOffset, Integer count) {
        this.auditor.audit(startTime, partnId, fromOffset, untilOffset, count);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param jsc
     * @param topicSet
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topicNames = "MySourceTopic";
        GenericLogic ec = new GenericLogic();
        Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> topicMap = null;
        try {

            topicMap = ec.getOffsets("MySourceTopic");

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        boolean clusterMode = false;

        Integer batchDuration = Integer.parseInt("30000");
        JavaSparkContext sparkConf = new JavaSparkContext("abcd.net:7077", "Kafka-Spark-Integration");

        sparkConf.getConf().set("spark.local.ip", "lock-dt-a4d.xyz.com");
        sparkConf.getConf().set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false");
        sparkConf.getConf().set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio");

        JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(10000));
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String pollInterval = "10000";
        String zookeeper = "lock-dt-a5d.xyz.com:2181,lock-dt-a6d.xyz.com:2181";

        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "lock-dt-a5d.xyz.com:9092,lock-dt-a6d.xyz.com:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "Consumer");
        kafkaParams.put("client.id", "Consumer");
        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);

        JavaInputDStream<byte[]> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jsc, String.class, byte[].class,
                StringDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, byte[].class, kafkaParams, topicMap,
                (Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, byte[]>, byte[]>) MessageAndMetadata::message);

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            if (rdd.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No events polled in last " + pollInterval + " milli seconds");
                return;
            }

            rdd.foreachPartition(itr -> {
                Integer partnId = TaskContext.get().partitionId();
                Long systime = System.nanoTime();
                Map<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                GenericLogic ec2 = new GenericLogic();
                ec2.setDefaultProperties();
                ec2.DBConnect();

                try {

                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("232");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            });
        });
        jsc.start();
        jsc.awaitTermination();
    }

}
```

Comment: in whichh configuration file u export HOSTNAME?

Comment: have you put that same property file in worker machines also?

Comment: i have properties file on all nodes. HOSTNAME should be a generic one right????i dont need to specify it in properties file. Isn't it?

Comment: when you are running it locally what value is given by System.env(HOSTNAME)

Comment: I didnt try it locally. But when i lauched the job System.env(HOSTNAME) is printing master node address.

Comment: Additionally, i ran a small jar which prints the HOSTNAME env variable on all nodes. This one printed hostname on all nodes. - public class envv {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("env=" + System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know OS of all the nodes and if you have ensured that noting on Master node is exporting the HOSTNAME. Answering your question will be better if you let us know about your OS detail.

May not be correctly related to your context but just for information System.getenv("HOSTNAME") may not provide hostname in all the platforms (for example Ubuntu or Mac).

Better is why not export the HOSTNAME.

Note: I am assuming you have already checked that props is not null or empty?
If not debug and check whether properties files is loaded or not and if loaded it is not the empty properties file and hence it has loaded the properties from the file.

Looking at your problem (not only environment variable but properties are also not returning, there may be something wrong with properties file or its relative location on different computers. 
If it is not exact copy which is placed at different computers, please also check if it is a file good for Linux (not written and edited in windows and put in linux).

Answer (score 0):

I started the salves with start-slaves.sh.
 That's the issue. I have to start workers by supplying master addres.